# XML castor ns-uri question

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, castor

i have this  xml / soap project.

there is everywhere something called `ns-uri` / namespace uri.

for example here:

```
<class name="org.webmedia.test.pojo.City">
       <map-to xml="addCityRequest" ns-uri="http://krams915.blogspot.com/ws/schema/oss"/>

       <field name="id" type="integer">
          <bind-xml name="id" node="element"/>
       </field>

       <field name="name" type="string">
          <bind-xml name="name" node="element"/>
       </field>
</class>
```

what is it for? can i change it? can i remove it? it leads to dead website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ns-uri` refers to a [XML namespace URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace). Without it, Castor's binding won't work properly.

Yes, you can change it (but it has to match the namespace URI of the target XML), and yes you can remove it (but it will likely generate/parse the wrong XML).  The fact that it's a dead URL doesn't matter - namespace URIs are just string identifiers that often *look* like URLs, but they don't have to go anywhere.